# Is using audio filters haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it halal for a sound editor to use an audio filter to amplify the voice of a person so that it becomes easier for people to hear his voice?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in increasing the voice of someone whether it was by a filter or just by resetting the volume of the device.

Why would you think it is Haram? I see no reason for that to be true as you are not talking about altering the voice of someone without his/her permission and still declaring that the altered voice is his/her real and actual voice. This would be related to fraud and cheating issues that are not legally nor Islamically accepted. They are forbidden indeed.

The Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) said:

> Whoever bears arms against us is not one of us, and whoever cheats us is not one of us.
>
> *(Saheeh Muslim)*

Muslims should avoid, besides deceit and cheating, treachery and lying despite the gains they may get; otherwise, they will be considered hypocrites according to the Hadith in which the Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) said:

> There are four characteristics, whoever has all of them is a true hypocrite, and whoever has one of them has one of the qualities of a hypocrite until he gives it up: when he is trusted, he betrays; when he speaks, he lies; when he makes a promise, he breaks it; and when he disputes, he resorts to slander.
>
> *(Saheeh Al-Bukhari, Saheeh Muslim)*

[Source](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/346/cheating-and-deception/)